# How to add all special characters in variable for sed command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, redhat

I have a variable called varname which have characters such as /,. etc. Requirement is to use it with sed command. This is what I've done.

```
echo Hello admin, please add , after you enter the image name
read -p varname
sed -i "s/my-images=/&$varname/" /home/myconfig
echo Image $varname has been added to the configuration. Thanks!!
```

/home/myconfig has

```
id=1
max-mb=1000
my-images=customimage
```

And required output is

```
id=1
max-mb=1000
my-images=mynewtext/version1,customimage
```

I am getting error while running this code and the error is : sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could escape all `/`'s in your variable with a backslash `\` (a literal `\` must be escaped as `\\`):

```
sed -i "s/my-images=/&${varname//\//\\/}/" /home/myconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have entered text with slash (as I can see you have mynewtext/version...), it will recognized as finish s command.
You can try to use another character as separator in sed, like:

```
sed -i "s#my-images=#&$varname#" /home/myconfig
```